# How to hide a field from anonymous users?

Tags: users

I've been searching for this for quite some time, but so far I haven't been able to find a good way to hide a field on my custom content type from anonymous users. I want some fields to be visible only to logged-in users. Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes.
> - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has.
> - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is.
> - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Have no idea why I couldn't find it earlier, I feel kind of stupid now ;) Thanks!